# Extracting continuos bits from a std::string bytewise with a bit offset

Tags: c++, string, bit-manipulation, intrinsics, bitset

I'm kind of at a loss i want to extract up to 64bits with a defined bitoffset and bitlength (unsigned long long) from a string (coming from network).

The string can be at an undefined length, so i need to be sure to only access it Bytewise. (Also means i cant use _bextr_u32 intrinsic). I cant use the std bitset class because it doesnt allow extraction of more then one bit with an offset and also only allows extraction of a predefined number of bits.

So I already calculate the byteoffset (within the string) and bitoffset (within the starting byte).

```
m_nByteOffset = nBitOffset / 8;
m_nBitOffset = nBitOffset % 8;
```

Now i can get the starting address

```
const char* sSource = str.c_str()+m_nByteOffset;
```

And the bitmask

```
unsigned long long nMask = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL >> (64-nBitLen);
```

But now I just cant figure out how to extract up to 64 bits from this as there are no 128 bit integers available.

```
unsigned long long nResult = ((*(unsigned long long*)sSource) >> m_nBitOffset) & nMask;
```

This only works for up to 64-bitoffset bits, how can i extend it to really work for 64 bit indepently of the bitoffset. And also as this is not a bytewise access it could cause a memory read access violation.

So im really looking for a bytewise solution to this problem that works for up to 64 bits. (preferably C or intrinsics)

Update: After searching and testing a lot I will probably use this function from RakNet:
https://github.com/OculusVR/RakNet/blob/master/Source/BitStream.cpp#L551

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it byte-wise, just read the string (which BTW it is better to interpret as a sequence of `uint8_t` rather than `char`) one byte at a time, updating your result by shifting it left 8 and `or`ing it with the current byte. The only complications are the first bit and the last bit, which both require you to read a part of a byte. For the first part simply use a bit mask to get the bit you need, and for the last part down shift it by the amount needed. Here is the code:

```
const uint8_t* sSource = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(str.c_str()+m_nByteOffset);

uint64_t result = 0;
uint8_t FULL_MASK = 0xFF;

if(m_nBitOffset) {
    result = (*sSource & (FULL_MASK >> m_nBitOffset));
    nBitLen -= (8 - m_nBitOffset);
    sSource++;
}

while(nBitLen > 8) {
    result <<= 8;
    result |= *sSource;
    nBitLen -= 8;
    ++sSource;
}

if(nBitLen) {
    result <<= nBitLen;
    result |= (*sSource >> (8 - nBitLen));
}

return result;
```

Comment: i like this division of the problem, this will work ill do some tests later today

Comment: A `static_cast` should work, since `const char*` should be compatible with `const uint8_t*`.  That would give you some safety against typos.

Comment: This is might compile to some pretty bad asm with gcc.  e.g. it might actually shift and load one byte at a time. :/  In asm, loading up-to-64bits that might not be byte-aligned should be doable with a byte-load, an unaligned 64bit load, and a couple shifts.  (And an `OR` if you don't use a 2-register shift like [x86's `shrd`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SHRD.html) to take a window of the concatenation of 2 regs).  Branches are optional, to skip the byte-load if one 64bit load can include the entire desired bitstring.  If you're lucky, though, you'll get asm like that from this src.

Comment: hm this code didn't work it shuffles the bytes wrong, endianness is destroyed.     

uint64_t nMask      = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL;
    uint64_t nPattern   = 0xFFFEFDFCFBFAF9F8ULL;
    uint64_t nPattern2  = 0xFAAAAAAAAAAAAAFFULL;

    EXPECT_EQ( nPattern, ExtractField( 0, 64, (uint8_t*)&nPattern) );

    EXPECT_EQ( nMask >> 1, ExtractField( 1, 63, (uint8_t*)&nMask) );
    EXPECT_EQ( nPattern >> 1, ExtractField( 1, 63, (uint8_t*)&nPattern) );
    EXPECT_EQ( nPattern2 >> 1, ExtractField( 1, 63, (uint8_t*)&nPattern2) );

Comment: Well OK, but you didn't specify the endianess of your input (`str.c_str()`) and I assumed it was network byte order. I guess you're saying the data is little endian instead?

Comment: yeah i expected it to just come out in the order i put it in (endianess i would have handled after the extraction with a swap), espacially with bits offset it needs to be read directly without rearraging bytes as this will not only destroy the endianess but also the data.

Comment: How exactly did you 'put it in'?

Comment: Because you see, big-endian (i.e. my implementation) IS reading the bits directly as they are put in, its little endian that would require fiddling

Comment: see the unit test cases above the first parameter is the offset, then length then the pattern, ill need todo some more debugging to figure out how to copy it out directly.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Is your real-life data presented to you in the same way, or is this just for a test? The norm for this kind of encoding is actually big-endian, that's why I'm asking. You can easily modify your test to produce big-endian input by the way, I can show you how if needs be

Comment: yeah in fact the byte order is not defined, it depends its a generalized packet field extraction, yeah if you have an idea for keeping the byte order the same i'd like to know. But it is still wrong Endianess defines Byteorder not Bitorder, but when using a bit offset one can not work on assuming another byteorder.

Comment: Change your unit tests along these lines (note: you will need `#include <endian.h>`): `...; uint64_t nPattern =  0xFFFEFDFCFBFAF9F8ULL; uint64_t be_nPattern = htobe64(nPattern); EXPECT_EQ(nPattern, ExtractField(0, 64, (uint8_t*)&be_nPattern); ....`

Comment: Note also you're doing something dodgy in treating a `uint64_t` as a sequence of `uint8_t`. Technically this is undefined behaviour. It would be better to explicitly create an `std::array<uint8_t, 8>` say, initialise it byte-wise with big-endian order, then compare it to your expected `uint64_t` result (defined separately)

Comment: In your case that would be `std::array<uint8_t, 8> be_nPattern = {0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFD, 0xFC, 0xFB, 0xFA, 0xF9, 0xF8};`

Comment: even after a swap of the 64bits the result is still wrong, it just doesnt take into account that bits also move between bytes in the middle case (when its not the end or start byte)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114739/discussion-between-hendrik-and-smeeheey).

Comment: So after some testing the solution works with these limitationsthe input data must be the reverse byte order of the output data, and the offset+length can't exceed 64 so basically it will still need some work

Comment: @Hendrik: Reading a byte at a time has the large advantage of making your code [endian-agnostic](https://commandcenter.blogspot.ca/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html).  If you might need to byte-swap, it makes sense to do it as part of deserializing the data.  Code that only reads a byte at a time and uses shifts to combine things only has to care about the network byte order, not the host byte order.  **You can loop forwards or backward depending on the byte order of the bitstring in the `std::string`**.  (i.e. modify this code to loop the other direction if you need.)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it in modern C++ style. 
The bit length is determined by the size of the buffer `extractedBits`: instead of using an `unsigned long long`, you could also use any other data type (or even array type) with the desired size.

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/369d254275bb74dc)

```
unsigned long long extractedBits;
char* extractedString = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&extractedBits);
std::transform(str.begin() + m_nByteOffset,
               str.begin() + m_nByteOffset + sizeof(extractedBits),
               str.begin() + m_nByteOffset + 1,
               extractedString,
               [=](char c, char d)
               {
                   char bitsFromC = (c << m_nBitOffset);
                   char bitsFromD = 
                       (static_cast<unsigned char>(d) >> (CHAR_BIT - m_nBitOffset));
                   return bitsFromC | bitsFromD;
               });
```

Comment: hm i tried this code as well, but even basic test cases fail also there isn't a bitlength used.

Comment: @Hendrik Updated! Now it works and I explained how to change the bit length.

Comment: I thought the OP's bitlength didn't have to be a power of 2, or even a multiple of 8, so e.g. the result could be 45 bits, stored in the low 45 of a 64bit integer (zero-extended to fill the upper 19 bits with 0).

Comment: exactly, thats why its missing. anyways i found now the function i require in RakNets bitstream processor.